# Why am I getting this extra message before destroy in Spring?

Tags: spring

Can anyone explain why I am getting this message at console before destruction of beans?

```
Jun 28, 2015 10:30:15 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1496d9f: startup date [Sun Jun 28 22:30:13 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
```

Getting this message before destroy method of disposableBean

I am not getting this message in every situation. In 2 situations, I am getting this.

1. while I used `BeanPostProcessor`
2. while I experimented on what happens, if I get my own init methods(defined in `bean.xml` by init-method) extended from some other class

Any idea anyone?

Comment: What situation is best suits for you?

Comment: Apart from getting the logging that confused me...the results are same..without extending or on extending the init method..but still not sure why only in specific scenarios i am getting the closeup log info

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Spring always writes to log (on INFO level) when application context is being closed. Take a look at sources http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/4.1.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.java#AbstractApplicationContext.doClose. You can switch this log output off if you set logging level to something above INFO (e.g WARN)

Comment: then why don't i get it every time on closure of application context. I am getting it in certain cases only even though the context is being closed. Is there some problem with some settings?